# Controller for reading an Emai - IPad App - Objective C/xcode

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, ipad

I want to compose or read an email from within my IPad application itself. Is there a way that I can implement this functionality ?? I mean is there any controller for reading an email ?? I am new to objective C. Thanks for help in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there's a way to read emails; unless you're implementing it using a UIWebView. (for all I know). However, this doesn't meet what you wish to do, since this will just load the email site; more like a browser.

Nevertheless, you can compose and send emails through MFMailComposeViewController (MessageUI framework). Try this useful [tutorial](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/mfmailcomposeviewcontroller/).

Answer (score 1):

There are no apis for reading the emails, for composing emails you can use `MFMailComposeViewController`  check the following [tutorial](http://geekios.wordpress.com/2011/11/05/how-to-send-mail-in-iphone-using-msmailcomposer-framework/)

Answer (score 1):

There isn't a way to read emails that I know of, but to show an email compose popup you can use the `MFMailComposeViewController` in the MessageUI framework.

```
MFMailComposeViewController* mail = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
[mail setMailComposeDelegate:self];
[self presentViewController:mail animated:YES completion:nil];
```

You will need to make your class conform to the `MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate` by adding it to your class header:

```
#import <MessageUI/MessageUI.h>

@class MyViewController : UIViewController <MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate> {
    ...
```

and implement it's callback method in your class somewhere:

```
-(void) mailComposeController:(MFMailComposeViewController *)controller didFinishWithResult:(MFMailComposeResult)result error:(NSError *)error {

    // Hide the message composer
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];

}
```

You'll also need to link to the MessageUI.framework.